# Need help in iteration array

Tags: arrays, batch-file

I need help to iterate the list in the following code, where `%list%` is `folder1 folder2 folder3`:

```
for %%c in (%list%) do (

    cd C:\Users\1026252\Desktop\%%c\


    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('findstr /i /c:"<span>" summary.html') do (
        set x="%%a"
        set x=!x:span^>=*@$!
        for /f "tokens=2 delims=*@$" %%b in (!x!) do (
            set y[%j%]="%%b"
            set y[%j%]=!y[%j%]:~1,-3!
            echo FINAL OUTPUT is: !y[%j%]!
            goto:BREAK
)
)
:BREAK
set /A "j+1"
@echo %j%

)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of my best guess of what you're trying to do, i.e. return the content between the first reached opening and closing `<span>` tags of any `summary.html` in each of the directories in `%list%`.

```bat
Set "j=0"
For %%A In (%list%) Do (Set /A j+=1
    Set "x="
    For /F "Tokens=*" %%B In (
        'FindStr /IC:"<span>" "C:\Users\1026252\Desktop\%%A\summary.html" 2^>NUL'
    ) Do If Not Defined y[!j!] (Set "x=%%B"
        For /F "Delims=<" %%C In ("!x:*<span>=!") Do (Set "y[!j!]=%%C"
            Call Echo FINAL OUTPUT is: %%y[!j!]%%)))
Pause
```

*Note:  This is not designed to work if there are other `<`'s between the `<span>` and `</span>` tags.*

Comment: Thanks man that's the fix i needed

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanya, if my answer is the preferred solution of those provided, please mark it as accepted, _by clicking on the large check mark to its left_.